# How to enable http2 in Azure?

Tags: azure, http2

Although I have enabled Http/2 in Azure, it is not working.
When I run locally my api, http/2 is working.

Edit 1

I have a net core 3 web api and I want to publish to an azure web app.
I followed the instructions of microsoft's page, but when I check the protocol on HttpContext.Request.Protocol I got HTTP/ 1.1.

Is something else that I should add to my code or other configuration on Azure web app that I missed?

Thanks

Comment: "Azure" is not a single service. Please clarify what you are talking about. Azure Web Apps?

Comment: Please can you specify which type of resource are you using?

Comment: It is an Azure web app

Answer (score 4):

In 2021, it's in your app service sidebar -> settings -> configuration.
[image]

From there it's under the "tab" general settings, halfway down the page.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about Azure web  app , you need to use resource explorer and change the “http20Enabled” to the desired value .

From resource explorer , follow this blog https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2018/04/18/how-to-disableenable-http2-azure-app-service/

Through the Azure portal, browse to your app and search for the “Application settings”, where you will find the setting called “HTTP Version”. Select 1.1 or 2.0 by your needs.

From portal, follow this official announcement https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-http-2-support-in-azure-app-service/?ref=msdn

If you have concern about any other azure service , do let me know.

Comment: http20Enabled is set to true. However I can't send an http2 request from my browser.

Comment: Note that HTTP/2 is SSL only on the browser side, see https://www.mnot.net/blog/2015/06/15/http2_implementation_status